# List Server Shares

Tags: c#, vb.net, server, wmi

I am trying to list the Shares on a Server like so:
[image]

I tried the following code:

```
    Dim objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\srv0000\root\CIMV2")
    Dim colShares = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Share")

    For Each objShare In colShares
        MsgBox("Name: " & objShare.Name)
    Next
```

But I get an error **Cannot create ActiveX component.** on line 1.

So I tried:

```
    Dim scope As ManagementScope = New ManagementScope("\\srv0000\root\CIMV2")
    scope.Connect()
    Dim worker As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, New ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM win32_share"))
    For Each share As ManagementObject In worker.Get
        MsgBox(share("Name"))
    Next
```

But I get the error **Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))** on line 2.

I do have access to the server as is shown in the photo above, but am not an administrator. I'd just like to list the Shares as explorer can. As I don't need to make edits to the Shares, is there another approach I can take that's less robust?

Thanks!

Comment: and c# tag for what ?

Comment: because this isn't a vb or c# specific issue.

Comment: I can understand C# and vb.net, so an answer in either is fine. I'm not sure what your point is?

Comment: What happens if you run the program as administrator?

Comment: My second attempt runs fine as an admin. I know my 2 approaches are used normally to observe or edit server shares, so I added a little more to the end of my original question. I don't need options as robust as WMI offers, and since the users are just listing the Shares I won't need to allow them admin permissions (assuming there is another way). Thanks!

Comment: Try setting the ManagementScope [ConnectionOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) with `.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;`, `.EnablePrivileges = true;` and `.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;`. You can set the `ConnectionOptions` in a `ManagementScope` constructor overload

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your suggestion, but it still didn't work for my non-admin users. I used an alternate method to WMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I ended up using the method provided here.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2939/Network-Shares-and-UNC-paths)